# Expose .NET class functions without wrapping them

Tags: c#, .net, com, comvisible

I have a `COMVisible` class **MyAPI** that my clients are going to use as the root object for all API access.

I have my APIs in another assembly **OtherAPI** that has *Document* and *Window* API classes (not COM visible).

I want to expose *Document* and *Window* classes via **MyAPI** class to a late binding client such as JavaScript.

```
[COMVisible(true)]
class MyAPI
{
    public OtherAPI::Document NewDocument()
    {
        return new OtherAPI::Document();
    }
}

// Something like this should work in the client code
(new MyAPI()).NewDocument().GetName();
```

The problem is that it does not see **GetName** because that is not `COM visible` I think.

I can wrap each and every function from Document and Window class in this class but I am looking for an elegant solution. I want my clients app to be able to use both Document and Window class functions via MyAPI object.

Comment: They are not com visible for a reason

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the documentation...

Important parts highlighted for you viewing pleasure :)

[ComVisibleAttribute Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> Setting the attribute to false on a specific type hides that type and
>   its members. However, you cannot make members of a type visible if the
>   type is invisible. Setting the attribute to false on a type prevents
>   that type from being exported to a type library; classes are not
>   registered; interfaces are never responsive to unmanaged
>   QueryInterface calls.

**However!**

> Unless you explicitly set a class **and its members** to false, inherited
>   classes can expose to COM base class members **that are invisible in the
>   original class**. For example, if you set **ClassA** to false **and do not
>   apply the attribute to its members**, the class and its members are
>   invisible to COM. However, if you derive **ClassB** from **ClassA** and export
>   **ClassB** to COM, **ClassA** members become visible base class members of
>   ClassB.

So it reads very clearly.

If you have marked the **parent class members** to false you cant expose them, however if its only the parent class that as been marked false (and the member aren't explicitly marked false), you can expose them.

Otherwise, you will have to re-implement them all again... Sorry, no free lunch here today